# a program that find words in any window opened on the desktop

Tags: text, colors, find, highlight, keyword

I was going to buy this program called hilitext (http://www.fanix.com/hilitext.html). According to its description, it does what I need to some extent. Unfortunately, it no longer works. Its developer has stopped updating it since couple years ago and they don't respond to my email. I have been searching for something similar to hilitext last couple days, I couldn't find anything like it. I'm thinking maybe I need to make it myself. I'm new to making a complete program. I need a little bit guidance on how to start, like what coding language, what compiler, what are the tools that I need to make a program like this? I'm not asking how to code it, I could look at some basic sample codes and figure out how to do the coding.

Here's the description of the program that I need to make:

-The program needs to store hundred of keywords that I input into it.

-The program scan any window opened on the desktop for the appearance of these keywords in real time.

-Once a keyword is found, its background color or its font color would be altered to a color I have chosen.

I have made a program like this with Excel visual basic, it works only in Excel and it has done the job for awhile. Unfortunately, the source of data is no longer accessible through Excel. That's why I need to make the program to work with any window opened on the desktop.

Of course, if such program already exists, please tell me about it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> -The program needs to store hundred of keywords that I input into it.

Hundreds is not that much. You can simply write it to a flat file and read it whenever you need it.

> -The program scan any window opened on the desktop for the appearance of these >keywords in real time.

This really depends on the program you'd like to scan. You can't simply read any open windows' content. Every type of application (microsoft office <-> internet explorer <-> java-based application <-> Qt-like <-> mainframe application <-> ...) would need it's own methodology.

I'd suggest limiting the scope..

> -Once a keyword is found, its background color or its font color would be altered >to a color I have chosen.

Same comments as above; limit the scope.

> I need a little bit guidance on how to start, like what coding language, what compiler, what are the tools that I need to make a program like this?

Generally, pick any coding language you'd like. I'd suggest a scripting language like python, as the syntax is pretty clear. Compiler depends on programming language you use.

Comment: The window I need to scan now is a java-based application. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: [Java programs are different because instead of using native controls, they custom paint the entire UI. ... Windows-specific grabbers don't work because all they see is a single window with a bunch of pixels.](http://superuser.com/a/512536)